# Ultimate css reset

Tags: css

**Is there a *complete* and *absolute* CSS reset?** Let me explain:

What if you are making your own browser with its unique default style sheet? Can that be reassemble with a reset.css?

I first thought about using:

```
* {display: none;}
```

But that won't do it, for once you display one element, I will render with the browser default style.

The best idea, I think, is to apply one specific value to every posible property, thus having all elements rendering the same. But, could that be done with only a few lines of CSS? Any ideas?

Comment: If you're making your own browser, why do *you* need a CSS reset?

Comment: If you are `making your own browser` you have the option to either use an existing layout engine (such as WebKit, Gecko, Trident) or creating your own.  If you are doing the former you've accepted that their default styles are appropriate, if the latter you're setting your own defaults so there is no need for a reset.

Comment: The problem with reset is that elements have different values, for example, some will be displayed in block, others inline. I want no default browser style being applied.

Answer (score 2):

The most famous and complete one is Eric Meyer's CSS reset: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the hard reset:

```
* {
all: unset;
}
```

But it has some bad browser support and doesn't work that correctly.

I recommend you to use the new Reseter.css - https://git.io/JtOhi